# Django: remotely access a PythonAnywhere MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, django, pythonanywhere

I have a Django app (Python 3.4, Django 1.7) on PythonAnywhere, along with a MySQL database.
**The database is working fine on the deployed app.**

However, I cannot get to connect it to the app on my local machine.

The following error is thrown when I run `python manage.py runserver`:

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: (2003, "2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.server:3306' (8 nodename nor servname provided, or not known)", None)

These are the attributes I use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': '<username>$<database_name>',
        'USER': '<username>',
        'PASSWORD': '<databse_password>',
        'HOST': 'pythonanywhere.com'
    }
}
```

I have also tried `mysql.server` and `mysql.server.pythonanywhere.com` as `HOST` without any more luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think It's not possible to connect directly to your mysqlserver instance from remote, for security reason, the port 3306 is blocked.
They suggest to connect through SSH Tunnel, follow this [link](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/SSHTunnelling).
I don't know If you can do an ssh tunnelling within Django, You should probably write a custom configuration. It's simpler to install an SSH Tunnel software on your PC and then connect your Django App to localhost on a port You have to choose.
Bye

Answer (score 3):

As per PythonAnyWhere documentation :

1. Open a terminal and run below command.

   ssh -L 3333:username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com:3306 username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com

provide your PAW account login password

replace username with your username.

2. Open another terminal and run below command.

   mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3333 -u username -p

provide your mysql password. Available in settings file.

keep terminal 1 open as long as you are working on terminal 2.

[Accessing PythonAnyWhere MySQL from outside](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere)

Comment: It came 2 years later but this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Only Paid account have permission to access remoteserver for mysql database

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).